# Reading XML database column in java

Tags: java, xml, database, db2

I have DB2 database with XML column. I would like to read data from it and save each XML to separate file.

Here is a part of my code:

```
final List<Map<String, Object>> myList = dbcManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    int i=0;
    for (final Map<String, Object> element : myList) {
        i++;
        String filePath = "C://elements//elem_" + i + ".xml";
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
        out.write(element.get("columnId"));
        out.close();
    }
```

Now, I have error in line out.write(element.get("columnId"));, because element.get("columnId") is an object type and it should be for example string.

And my question is: To which type should I convert (cast) element.get("columnId") to save it in xml file?

Comment: http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2008/04/12/db2-native-xml/ might help

Answer (score 1):

You should use the ResultSet.getSQLXML() method to read the XML column value, then use an appropriate method of the SQLXML class, e.g. getString() or getCharacterStream(). [More info here.](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/c0021817.html)